# Initialize constructor with multiple parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting this error `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)` when I try to save a log in database.

```
logs_transactions = Logs_transactions('test', 'test', 910000000, current_user.id)
db.session.add(logs_transactions)
db.session.commit()

class Logs_transactions(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'logs_transactions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(100))
    reference = db.Column(db.String(500))
    phone_number = db.Column(db.Integer)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users_user.id'))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

I know that i can use something like this:

```
def __init__(self, type, reference, phone_number, user_id):
    self.type = type
    self.reference = reference
    self.phone_number = phone_number
    self.user_id = user_id
```

But this way is annoying if I have many parameters. So I am thinking that the constructor above is equivalent, but apparently is not working. Basically I want to avoid the explicit self.xxx for all parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are not equivalent.  `kwargs` takes keywords, you're passing positional arguments.  SQLAlchemy models already have an initializer that takes kwargs, you don't need to provide your own.

```
Logs_transaction(type='test', reference='test', ...)
```